# virtual-machine (vm image) of java development environment with an app server and database

Tags: spring, hibernate, download, virtual-machine, development-environment

I am looking for a free downloadable vmware image with java development environment; an app server and database is installed/set up. I will be using it for personal educational purpose. It would be nice, if I get some running hello world examples in different latest java technologies (Spring, hibernate, JSF). I prefer guest OS as windows.

Greatly appreciate if someone can send a link to download this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Oracle website gives similar to what I was looking. Not sure, if I can expect a windows image.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/weblogic/downloads/weblogic-developer-vm-303434.html